# Open existing indexedDB Database using dexie.js?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have an existing indexedDB Database with the name of "APPV1" with version number "0.1".

```
indexedDB.open("APPV1", "1.0");
```

I want to use the [dexie.js](https://dexie.org/) wrapper for indexedDB.

My question was how can I open the existing DB with dexie?

How can I add tables with existing DB with dexie?

How can I access data's with the help of dexie?

*Note*: I read their documentation and I'm not sure about how can they access the existing indexedDB using dexie.js

Answer (score 0):

This topic should be covered here: https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Migrating-existing-DB-to-Dexie

*Edit: I just now updated dump-databases.html to allow converting a non-dexie database into Dexie code. (This was not needed before but since chromium removed the webkitGetDatabaseNames() API). So if your DB is created outside Dexie, press the Add Database button and enter the name of the DB to be able to dump it.*

Comment: Hi @David Fahlander. Sorry for the late reply. Can you show some code that really open's my APPV1 DB with the help of dexie.js ?

Comment: If you want to open it just dynamically, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dfahlander/b8Levamm/ . For you it would be new Dexie("APPV1").open(). 

That said, having the object stores declared using version(x).stores({...}) can make your application code easier to work with than opening it dynamically like this.